# get current url in IE addon VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have an IE addon and I want to get the current url when i click on a button I have try

```
`url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`

`msgBox(url)`
```

and I all get is an alert box without anything.

I have try everything I found on the internet and none of it work. So I am thinking is it id different for a vb.net IE addon

Please help

Comment: [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext(v=vs.110).aspx)  is part of asp.net it can't be used in addon.

Comment: @IvanH thanks for your reply so in addon what can I use?